# Revisiting the product rule for derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, derivatives

> Let $E=C^{\infty}(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$
>
> Consider a linear transformation on $E$: $\delta$ such that $\forall f, g \in E, \delta(fg) =g\delta(f) +f\delta(g)$
>
> Prove that there is some $u\in E$ such that $\forall f\in E, \delta(f) =uf'$

My answer is that $u:x\to \delta(Id)(0)$ where $Id$ denotes the identity function.

It is very easy to prove that $\delta$ annihilates constant functions.

Consider a fixed $x_0$ and  these few functions :

$\displaystyle g:x \to \frac{f(x_0+x)-f(x_0)}{x}$

$ \displaystyle h:x \to f(x_0+x)-f(x_0)$

$ \displaystyle m:x \to f(x_0+x)$

All these functions belong to $E$.

Let $x\in \mathbb R$

$\delta(Id\times g) (x) =x\delta(g(x)) + g(x) \delta(Id) (x) $

Hence

$\delta(h) (x) =\delta(m) (x) =x\delta(g(x)) + g(x) \delta(Id) (x) $

Now, let $x\to 0$

The RHS becomes $f'(x_0) \delta(Id) (0)$ since $\delta(g) $ is bounded around $0$.

**Question**

But why is $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\delta(m)(x)=\delta(f)(x_0)$?

It is very intuitive, but I fail finding a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can verify that for any $u \in E$, the rule $\delta(f) = uf'$ defines a derivation of $E$, i.e. an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $\delta: E \to E$ with the property that $\delta(fg) = g\delta(f) + f\delta(g)$. It is not necessary that the coefficient $u$ be a real *constant*, as the definition "$u : x \mapsto \delta(\operatorname{Id})(0)$" in your post suggests. The function $u$ will be constant if and only if $\delta$ commutes with all operators $T_a : E \to E$, where for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we define $T_a(f)(x) = f(x+a)$. In fact, the last formula in your post claims that $\delta(T_{x_0}f)(0) = T_{x_0}(\delta f)(0)$, which is not true in general.

Assuming that $\delta(f) = uf'$ for some $u \in E$ and putting $f = \operatorname{Id}$ in this equality, we obtain $u = \delta(\operatorname{Id})$ (no evaluation at $x=0$). One possible way to prove that this indeed is the case, is as follows. Fix $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the Taylor formula with integral form of the remainder
$$ f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + R(x)(x-x_0)^2, \quad \text{where} \quad R(x) = \int_{0}^{1} (1-t)\,f''((1-t)x_0 + tx)\,dt.$$
Since $f \in E$, it is possible to differentiate the integrand in the definition of $R$ any number of times, to show that $R \in E$, as well. Now, apply $\delta$ to both sides of Taylor's formula, and then put $x=x_0$ in the resulting equality. This would give us the relation $\delta(f)(x_0) = f'(x_0)\delta(\operatorname{Id})(x_0)$. Since this is valid for any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, we conclude that $\delta(f) = \delta(\operatorname{Id})\cdot f'$.

Comment: Nice solution. Does this operator have a special name, is it referenced somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure which operator you are referring to. The derivations $\delta : E \to E$ are usually called *vector fields*. They come up in subjects like differential geometry, ordinary differential equations, etc. The operators of the form $T_a : E \to E$ are sometimes called *translation operators*. Analogous operators can be defined on an arbitrary Lie group. Translationally invariant differential operators (i.e. linear differential operators with constant coefficients) on $\mathbb{R}^n$ appear in the classical equations of mathematical physics (such as the heat, wave and Laplace equations).

Comment: Oh... Derivations... Do you know a book that covers them?

Comment: You can find out more about derivations in books on differential geometry/analysis on manifolds, commutative algebra, etc. You may wish to have a look e.g at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra) or http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Derivation_in_a_ring, and/or some of the references listed there.